# laravel return Redirect inside function

Tags: laravel

I have this code on my controller but the return doesn't work because it's inside a function, how can I make it work?
I do it to ensure that the data is saved on the database and the redirect to panel.

```
public function save(){
 .
 .
 .
 Offer::saved(function($offer)                
 {
    Log::info('saved'); 
    //send email, etc.
    return Redirect::to('/panel');
 });
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to make that redirect inside the `saved` event?

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
public function save(){
    if($offer->save()){
        return Redirect::to('/panel');
    }
}
```

(`save()` will return true if everything went down well)

---

However if you *really really* need to do it in the event, you can call `send()` to "return" the response manually:

```
Offer::saved(function($offer)                
{
    Log::info('saved'); 
    Redirect::to('/panel')->send();
});
```

### Edit

For a query like: `DB::table('offers')->where('id',$inputs['id'])->update($fields);`

You can check the return value too. The `update` method will return a count of affected rows. So if that is `> 0` or *truthy* the record was updated.

```
$affectedRows = DB::table('offers')->where('id',$inputs['id'])->update($fields);
if($affectedRows){
    return Redirect::to('/panel');
}
```

But if you have set up your Eloquent model, why even bother with the Query Builder:

```
$offer = Offer::find($inputs['id']);
$saved = $offer->update($fields);
if($saved){
    return Redirect::to('/panel');
}
```

Comment: yeah, the idea to redirect inside "saved" is to ensure that the data is well storaged on the database, but is you say that 'if($offer->save())' is fine, i will simple use it. Thank you. +10pts

Comment: But, how can i do in this case?

` DB::table('offers')->where('id',$inputs['id'])->update($fields); ` i cant verify with  `if ($offer->save())`  ? ?

Comment: i think in this case i should use `Redirect::to('/panel')->send();`

Comment: No not really. You realize that when you use `DB::table()... ->update` the `saved` event won't fire because that's attached to your Eloquent model? I've updated my answer, take a look :)